Why do I get "SDL2.dll not found" error when loading .png files with SDL3 and SDL2_image library
To load .png file to window using SDL3 and SDL2_image library, I downloaded the following code from the link below:
https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/06_extension_libraries_and_loading_other_image_formats/sdl3-06_extension_libraries_and_loading_other_image_formats.zip
#include <SDL3/SDL.h>
#include <SDL3/SDL_main.h>
#include <SDL3_image/SDL_image.h>
#include <string>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

//Starts up SDL and creates window
bool init();

//Loads media
bool loadMedia();

//Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();

//Loads individual image
SDL_Surface* loadSurface( std::string path );

//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

//The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;

//Current displayed PNG image
SDL_Surface* gPNGSurface = NULL;

bool init()
{
    //Initialization flag
    bool success = true;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( !SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) )
    {
        SDL_Log( "SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0 );
        if( gWindow == NULL )
        {
            SDL_Log( "Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Initialize PNG loading
            int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
            if( !( IMG_Init( imgFlags ) & imgFlags ) )
            {
                SDL_Log( "SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Get window surface
                gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow );
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}

bool loadMedia()
{
    //Loading success flag
    bool success = true;

    //Load PNG surface
    gPNGSurface = loadSurface( "loaded.png" );
    if( gPNGSurface == NULL )
    {
        SDL_Log( "Failed to load PNG image!\n" );
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}

void close()
{
    //Free loaded image
    SDL_DestroySurface( gPNGSurface );
    gPNGSurface = NULL;

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}

SDL_Surface* loadSurface( std::string path )
{
    //The final optimized image
    SDL_Surface* optimizedSurface = NULL;

    //Load image at specified path
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load( path.c_str() );
    if( loadedSurface == NULL )
    {
        SDL_Log( "Unable to load image %s! SDL_image Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Convert surface to screen format
        optimizedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface( loadedSurface, gScreenSurface->format );
        if( optimizedSurface == NULL )
        {
            SDL_Log( "Unable to optimize image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), SDL_GetError() );
        }

        //Get rid of old loaded surface
        SDL_DestroySurface( loadedSurface );
    }

    return optimizedSurface;
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //Start up SDL and create window
    if( !init() )
    {
        SDL_Log( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        //Load media
        if( !loadMedia() )
        {
            SDL_Log( "Failed to load media!\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            //Main loop flag
            bool quit = false;

            //Event handler
            SDL_Event e;

            //While application is running
            while( !quit )
            {
                //Handle events on queue
                while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
                {
                    //User requests quit
                    if( e.type == SDL_EVENT_QUIT )
                    {
                        quit = true;
                    }
                }

                //Apply the PNG image
                SDL_BlitSurface( gPNGSurface, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

                //Update the surface
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
            }
        }
    }

    //Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;
}

To setup SDL3 and SDL_Image library:

I downloaded and setup SDL3-devel-3.1.6-mingw.zip file from the link below for SDL3 installation:

https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/preview-3.1.6

I downloaded and setup SDL2_image-devel-2.8.2-mingw.zip file from the link below for SDL_image installation:

https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/releases

I copied the following directories from SDL2_image-2.8.2 under SDL3 directory.

686-w64-mingw32
x86_64-w64-mingw32
cmake

I created a directory named "SDL3_image" under "SDL3\686-w64-mingw32\include" directory and copied the file from the link below "SDL_image.h" to this directory.

https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/blob/main/include/SDL3_image/SDL_image.h

For project settings in CodeBlocks 20.03 32 bit:

Project Build options



I copied the files below to the .exe file directory.

SDL3.dll
SDL2_image.dll
The program compiles without any problems, but when I run it, it gives the error "SDL2.dll not found".
The examples except loading .png files with SDL3 work fine. Could there be a bug in loading the SDL3_image library or what am I missing?
Both settings below have the same functionality and give "undefined reference to 'IMG_Init'" error message

Build log


SDL2_image, as the name implies, is for SDL2, not for SDL3.
It seems a version of SDL_image for SDL3 wasn't released yet, but but they do support SDL3 in their main branch. So you'll have to build SDL_image from source.

I downloaded the source code and created a dll project named "SDL3_image" in CodeBlocks. I compiled the project without any problem and get a file named "SDL3_image.dll".
After copying the relevant files under the SDL3 directory, when I wanted to compile the project that loaded the png file, I received the error message "cannot find -lSDL3_image.dll".
I think I couldn't compile correctly with CodeBlocks.

@Niteya You shouldn't create the project yourself. Build it using CMake, that's the intended approach. Even though you got SDL3_image.dll, I can't be sure it was made correctly because you didn't follow the right procedure (CMake). Then the correct flag is -lSDL3_image, which will look for libSDL3_image.dll.a (or libSDL3_image.a or some other options, including the DLL). If it can't find libSDL3_image.dll.a, pass the directory that contains it to the -L flag.

@HolyBlackCatI build the source code using CMake to get a Project for CodeBlocks. Then, I compiled and linked the Project with CodeBlocks. I get SDL3_image.dll and libSDL3_image.dll.a files. If I use the -lSDL3_image flag, I get "cannot find -lSDL3_image" error. If I use "-lSDL3_image.dll", I get "undefined reference to 'IMG_Init'" error message.

@Niteya As I said, if it says cannot find -lSDL3_image, you need to pass the directory containing libSDL3_image.dll.a to -L.

@HolyBlackCatUsing libSDL3_image.dll.a in the "Link libraries"  or using -lSDL3_image.dll in the "Other linker options" of "Linker settings" give the same result: "undefined reference to 'IMG_Init'" error message. Using -lSDL3_image flag in CodeBlocks without .dll extension gives "cannot find -lSDL3_image" error.

@Niteya "Using -lSDL3_image flag in CodeBlocks without .dll extension gives "cannot find -lSDL3_image" error" I already told you (twice!) how to fix it. If you have this file at e.g. C:\foo\bar\libSDL3_image.dll.a, you need to pass -LC:/foo/bar -lSDL3_image. You can paste this to the "other linker flags" (or how is that field called in CB).

@HolyBlackCatCan you check out the last image I added to the original post?

@Niteya Hmm. Can you show the build log?

@HolyBlackCatI added build log image to the original post.

@Niteya Try removing -static.

@HolyBlackCatNothing has changed.

@Niteya Then my best guess is that you've compiled SDL_image using a different compiler than the one you're using right now. Do you have multiple MinGW versions installed?

@HolyBlackCatI have multiple MingW versions installed, but I changed CMake CMAKE_CODEBLOCKS_EXECUTABLE variable shows the compiler in CodeBlocks 20.03 32 bit IDE and SDL3_DIR variable shows SDL3 (Version 3.1.3)

@HolyBlackCatYou were right. The problem was caused by different MingW versions. Setting the CMAKE CODE BLOCKS EXECUTABLE variable does not change the result. After deleting the C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin definition in the system path variable and adding the CodeBlocks 20.03 MingW path definition in its place, the program worked without any problems. Thank you for your help.
